# PHP Unit Not Recognising Incorrect Class Name On Localhost

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

So I have a unit test running that is checking for a page redirect and that the page is displaying some text. The test passes on my localhost as I'd expect and I can browse to the page. I noticed however when I uploaded the site to a server and browsed to the page I got a 500 Error and on digging in to it further it turned out I'd use `auth::user()` instead of `Auth::user()` and so I got a class not found error.

How come PHP Unit on my localhost still processes `auth::()` correctly instead of providing a class error like the production server does? Or rather, how come my PHP environment allows the lowercase `auth` to still be processed. Is there a setting I can do somewhere that makes it process as strictly on my localhost as on the server?

Comment: Can you share the code from your test and the relevant line where it should be failing?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson I think on Googling because I'm using a Mac for development and Linux for the production server that OSX is case-insensitive where as linux is case sensitive which is why the problem doesn't occur on my localhost. Is there any setting in PHP so I can force it to be case aware? I'm using Composer and Laravel by the way in case that changes anything.

Comment: I can confirm this happens, I've just replicated what you mention on your question. Doing a `use` of `Auth` allows you to call `auth::` on the test and it resolves to a mock. Also happens with tinker so I guess that behaviour is expected, so maybe what's acting wrong is the production server.